# React useEffect/componentDidMount vs. state hook + function

Tags: reactjs

It seems to me that one could replace useEffect/componentDidMount with a state hook and function components. For example, if I wanted to make a fetch in useEffect or componentDidMount, I could simply create a function component that rendered the component that needed fetching, add the fetching method in the function (which will execute upon rendering) which modifies a state hook (so that once the data arrives, the page will re-render with the data). Since React has selective rendering, any other part of the function component that gets updated won't cause an unnecessary fetch.

Am I correct in saying this? Are there any other specific instances where useEffect/componentDidMount is strictly better?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why you want to replace `componentDidMount` in class component or `useEffect` with a custom function for the use case you highlighted but those two are different in terms of behavior, `componentDidMount` is one functionality that `useEffect` provides in function component. `useEffect` is a combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and you can have mulitple useEffect on one function component. `useEffect` accept array of values that could make it run again, all you do is specify those value for that particular useCase you wanted and whenever that values changes the `useEffect` is called, for UI changes you attach your `useState` to your logic and if followed accordingly you wont get unnecessary fetch request, if you want `useEffect` to be called just once then attach just an empty array like this `useEffect(()=>{//your fetch logic here },[])`

Comment: Right. But my question was more so, could you not replicate this behavior without using useEffect/componentDidMount? I'm wondering if these methods are necessary or more out of convenience.

Comment: The methods are neccessary because they are built into the core of react, if you know react you will  know that the library was built with `life cycle` management of components that is how to manage life cycle of component and if you dont use those methods, its as good as one writing his own framework, but never the less you can still try, but i dont think thats possible